# How should my query be?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
    date,               flag
    22/05/13             1
    22/05/13             1
    22/05/13             0
    23/05/13             1
    23/05/13             0
```

So I need a query where I count in different columns the 2 possible values of flag.

```
    date       flag1        flag0
    22/05/13    2            1
    23/05/13    1            1
```

How should I write my query in order to get the data in the way I showed above?

Comment: What is the data type of your date column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    [date]
    SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.flag=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flag0,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tbl.flag=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flag1
FROM
    tbl
GROUP BY
    tbl.[date]
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter the sql fiddle is summing flag=1 on both -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05d4e/3

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's from an older version of the post.  He's fixed it since then.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT [date], sum(flag) "flag1", sum(1-flag) "flag0"
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [date]
```

Normally I'd use a case statement inside the SUM() functions, but in this case it works out that we can get away with simple (and faster) expressions.

Comment: +1 (Unless flag is a bit datatype, which can't be summed. Then you do need a CASE statement.)

Comment: @criticalfix or cast to an int

Answer (score 2):

You could use the PIVOT function to get the result:

```
select date, [1] as flag1, [0] as flag0
from yt
pivot
(
  count(flag)
  for flag in ([1], [0])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1711/1)